Maven Workflow Fails to Deploy artifact into Github Packages
I've been trying to publish an artifact into github packages using this guide, but I am getting the following error:
Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-deploy-plugin:3.1.1:deploy (default-deploy) on project bughouse-fen-validator: Failed to deploy artifacts: Could not find artifact org.bughouse.fen:bughouse-fen-validator:pom:1.0 in github (https://maven.pkg.github.com/tim-bits/bughouse-fen-validator)
The artifact is obviously created as the following line in the log indicates:[INFO] Installing /home/runner/work/bughouse_fen_validator/bughouse_fen_validator/target/bughouse-fen-validator-1.0.jar to /home/runner/.m2/repository/org/bughouse/fen/bughouse-fen-validator/1.0/bughouse-fen-validator-1.0.jar
Workflow file content is as follows:
name: Maven Package

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
  workflow_dispatch:
  release:
    types: [created]

jobs:
  publish:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    permissions:
      contents: read
      packages: write
      deployments: write
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v4
    - name: Set up JDK 17
      uses: actions/setup-java@v4
      with:
        java-version: '17'
        distribution: 'temurin'

    - name: Publish to GitHub Packages Apache Maven
      run: mvn -X --batch-mode deploy
      env:
        GITHUB_TOKEN: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }}

Pertaining parts of pom as follows:
    <distributionManagement>
        <repository>
            <id>github</id>
            <name>GitHub Packages</name>
            <url>https://maven.pkg.github.com/tim-bits/bughouse-fen-validator</url>
        </repository>
    </distributionManagement>

    <plugin>
       <artifactId>maven-deploy-plugin</artifactId>
       <version>3.1.1</version>
    </plugin>

Would be grateful for any suggestions.

Just tested and it's working fine for me. See workflow, its run and the published package.

Apparently, your repo name has underscores and not dashes. See https://github.com/tim-bits/bughouse_fen_validator and compare with https://maven.pkg.github.com/tim-bits/bughouse-fen-validator (url). So, it's a typo. Please verify and confirm.

@Azeem, yes, it was an issue with the url naming, and after I've corrected it, everything worked - thanks so much!
If memory serves though, it was not a typo per se, but just my misunderstanding: when I initially implemented it this way a while ago, I must have named the url after the artifact name (i.e. bughouse-fen-validator) and not the repo name (i.e. bughouse_fen_validator),  which was incorrect nonetheless.
